# Load file into hive with long text column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to load a `.csv` file into hive, the file looks like this :

[image]

I tried using `load data inpath 's3://testinghiveme/T.csv' into table data;`

but it results all `NULLS`

[image]

I am not able to load the data with large text into hive column, I tried using delimited in create script but doesn't work.

```
create table t(id int...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;


hive> describe t;
OK
id                      int
posttypeid              int
acceptedanswerid        int
parentid                int
creationdate            varchar(20)
deletiondate            varchar(20)
score                   int
viewcount               int
body                    varchar(500)
owneruserid             int
ownerdisplayname        varchar(50)
lasteditoruserid        int
lasteditordisplayname   varchar(100)
lasteditdate            varchar(20)
lastactivitydate        varchar(20)
title                   varchar(100)
tags                    varchar(100)
answercount             int
commentcount            int
favoritecount           int
closeddate              varchar(20)
communityowneddate      varchar(20)
```

Comment: can you show the `describe table` ?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhalaI have added.

Comment: @GI.JOE if you will look closely you have `,` (field separator) in your payload. And I think this is what screwing up hive table. I think your text is surrounded by quotes if so I think you are better of using `opencsv` serde.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to user escape character in DDL which is available with CSVserde.
Or you could use delimiter other than comma.